# office365 Excel and TEXT() formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, locale

Excel allows to combine formatting with [`TEXT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c), e.g.:

```
=TEXT(B2, "ddd")
=A2&" " &TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

But if I try to do this on office365 it just display that text (does not work). What's wrong?

UPDATE: `B2` contains `01.01.2022` formatted with `d.m.` thus displayed as `1.1.` (my locale setup). But just direct formatting as `ddd` with cell content `=B2` works as expected. But I need to combine day with other text.

I'm using Czech locale. It might be locale specific: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/in-excel-office-365-text-function-does-not-work-correct/m-p/1786188.

Comment: what is in B2?  could it be a date that is actually a string that looks like a date, and cannot be converted naturally?

Comment: If you change the format to general on b2 does it change to a number like 44562?

Comment: Also, what is your local language?  could it be that you should use something different for year besides `y`?

Comment: Yes, changing B2 to "general` changes number to `44562`. My language is Czech, IMHO it's not a formatting issue because `ddd` itself works, but `=TEXT(B2, "ddd")` not. I guess it's another office365 limitation :(.

Comment: What Excel build are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound `16.0.14722.31879` (it's office365).

Comment: @pevik - Office 365 has several release channels.  So do you have an insider preview build install, since 14527.20276, is the November 09 2021 (2110) release. I can't find where 16.0.14722.31879 has been released to the stable release channel. In fact (2112) is 14718.20000 (released on November 26) which is lower than the build you specified.  Are you positive you provided the correct build number?

Answer (score 3):

The
[TEXT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)
seems to be broken on Office 365.

I downloaded from the above link using the link of
[Download Excel TEXT function examples](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/8/6A818B0B-06F4-4E41-80DE-D383A3B89865/TEXT%20function%20examples.xlsx),
and this is what this worksheet from Microsoft looks like,
completely broken:

[image]

You could complain to Microsoft on the Feedback Hub.

As a workaround, you could use the functions
YEAR, MONTH and DAY.

Comment: Is it possible to workaround it somehow?

Comment: @pevik - You could also potentially determine what specific build the function is broken within and downgrade or upgrade your build.

Comment: @Ramhound I can ask the admin, if it's possible to upgrade the build. But as harrymc has it also broken, it might not be supported.

Comment: Hmmmm, I am using build 14701.20166 and it works.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Interesting. Mine is Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270 64-bit. Excel insists it's up to date.

Comment: Just updated to version 21111 build 14701.20170, I am on the preview channel.  It still works, so either it has been fixed and not pushed out or it is a language thing like the OP found.

Comment: @pevik: I added one workaround I could think of to my answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Might be some obscure combination of region and language.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, it's locale dependent. I'm using Czech locale, thus I cannot use the default English  [`TEXT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function, but Czech locale one [`HODNOTA.NA.TEXT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/hodnota-na-text-funkce-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c):

```
=HODNOTA.NA.TEXT(B2; "ddd")
```

Comming from LibreOffice on Linux, this is really big difference for me.

Comment: I think this is related: https://superuser.com/questions/1689316/excel-text-formula-error-only-for-some-regional-users

Answer (score 0):

More generally I see this problem if you format a cell as Text, then enter a formula and Excel takes it literally and keeps showing the formula as a piece of text.

Test: use the simplest possible formula "=B2" and see what you get, to prove if this is to do with localisation of functions, or the TEXT function in O365 (which works for me, albeit in English).

If that is the problem, just format as "General", then enter the formula, then format as text (if you still want to).

Answer (score -1):

The other aspect of locale dependency is that the abbreviations used for the date components might differ from the English version.

For instance, day might be "d" based, so "Mon" might still come from "ddd" — as expected, so no loss if not thought about. But in the same language versions, maybe year is a different abbreviation, so perhaps "tttt" instead of "yyyy" and while the function using just "ddd" would work as expected, when it uses "mm/dd/yyyy" if fails since it needs "mm/dd/tttt"... not the case here as using the locale function name solved the problem, but sometimes this can be a person's problem.

Rears its head in another way:  such and such works nicely in the cell function, but fails in VBA. Or vice versa. Because VBA is flat-out English based and the functions vary by locale. Used to writing the parameters in one, you can easily forget once here and there.

In the case of the Czech language version, "rrrr" would be required instead of "yyyy". So "mm/dd/yyyy" WOULD fail while "ddd" would work. Change to "mm/dd/rrrr" and it should work nicely. (And yet, the same thing done in VBA would still require "yyyy" not "rrrr"...)